# Given the address of a pointer, how do I get what it points to?

Tags: c

If I am given the address of a pointer, how do I get what the pointer points to?

Comment: Do you know what it points to? Or do you have something like a `void*`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might mean:

```
/**
  * @param pointer_to_pointer_to_int: the address of a pointer to an integer.
 **/
void function_that_takes_pointer_to_pointer(int **pointer_to_pointer_to_int) {
    int the_int = **pointer_to_pointer_to_int;
    printf("The pointer points to %d\n", the_int);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it is a valid pointer, you can [dereference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) it using the unary `*` operator:

```
int *ptr = ...;
int x;
x = *ptr;
```

Comment: ...unless it's a pointer of type `void *` or `uintptr_t` which cannot be directly dereferenced.

Answer (score 1):

The unary `*` operator.

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr = 45;
printf("address: %p, value: %d", ptr, *ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to be given the address of a pointer is through a pointer to a pointer. If the value the pointer points to is an integer, the type of the address of the pointer is `int **`.

To get the pointer to the integer, you need to dereference the double pointer. Then you can dereference the integer pointer to get the integer value.

To dereference a pointer, use the `*` operator.

```
int **double_pointer = given;
int *int_pointer = *double_pointer;
int value = *int_pointer;
```

You can also chain the dereferences to do that on one line.

```
int **double_pointer = given;
int value = **double_pointer;
```

Answer (score 0):

The unary `*` operator returns or sets the value at a memory location.

For example:

```
int val = 42;
int* ptr = &val;
assert(val == *ptr);
```

If you have the address of a *pointer*, you would write `**pointerpointer`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers to your question depending on whether the compiler has a clue about the data that's referred or not.

Declaring a pointer of type `int *`, `char *` or `mytype *` instructs the compiler that a later attempt to dereference it using the unary `*` operator must yield a result of `int`, `char` or `mytype` respectively.

In the other case you would normally store a pointer either in a `void *` (generic, untyped pointer) or in a `uintptr_t` (an unsigned int the same size of a pointer, but without pointer semantics). In such a case the compiler doesn't have a clue how to interpret the dereferencing operator, so you must explicitly cast such a pointer to another pointer type, and only then dereference it:

```
int x = 5;
void *p = &x; /* p now points to an int, but the compiler doesn't know it */
printf("%d\n", *((int *) p)); /* we know what we did and don't rely on the compiler */
printf("%d\n", *p); /* compile-time error, dereferencing has undefined semantics */
```

Note that in compiled, unmanaged languages like C there is no runtime information about what kind of data a pointer is pointing to, unlike languages like Java where you can use the `instanceof` operator to check what a reference is really pointing to at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of RedX's comment, If you have a situation like

```
void foo(void *ptr)
{
  ...
}
```

where the value of `ptr` is a pointer to a pointer to `int`, for example, you could do something like

```
void foo(void *ptr)
{
  int x = **((int **) ptr);
  ...
}
```

Basically, you cast `ptr` to `int **`, then double-dereference it.

If you *don't* know what the target type is ahead of time (e.g., the function is meant to handle pointers to multiple types), then you're going to have to figure out a way to encode that type information in a second argument and pass it to the function.